Create a new sheet tab for Google Form responses every day
I have a forum that is collecting responses and I'd like to automatically have the spreadsheet create a new sheet tab each day, and then populate that sheet tab with any Google Form responses for that date. For example, if I had 2 respones today, 11/08/2024, I'd like to have a sheet tab named 11-08 created in the morning, and those two responses automatically copied over from the Form Respones sheet to the 11-08 sheet tab. I tried with the code in the screenshot, but the query function I've created won't work with setformula in Apps Script. Is their any easier way to go about what I'm trying to do, or a way to set that query function to a cell automatically? Thanks in advance!
This is the code I used in Apps Script. I can get it to run and create a new sheet tab daily, and work with a simple formula, but not with the query formula I'm using to try and grab any results with todays date. I included a second screen shot of the intended result (I manually put in the query formula in cell A1).enter image description here
function createNewDailyTab() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

  sheet.insertSheet(today); 
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(today);
  sheet.activate();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(0);
  
 var cell = sheet.getRange("BA");
 cell.setFormula("=query('2024-11'!A2:H,"Select * Where A= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)");

}


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Scattering data across many tabs is seldom productive. You can create a helper column that extracts dates with =arrayformula(to_date(iferror(datevalue(A2:A)))), and then view the data by date using a Group by view or a filter view.

Reiterating @doubleunary, It's a bad idea to create multiple sheets for just filtering purposes.

Use onFormSubmit(e) to Create a New Sheet Tab Every Form Submit
First of all, I used onFormSubmit so you don't have to add the Query formula every single time it creates a Sheet Tab.
I modified your code where it automatically creates a sheet tab based on the date when you submit the form. It also copies the data that you have input in the form.

First, you will need to change your Function name to Installable trigger called onFormSubmit so that the code will trigger every form submit.

Here is the full code:
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = e.values;  
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[0]), "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var sheetnames = ss.getSheets().map(x=>x.getSheetName());

  if (!sheetnames.includes(date)) {
    ss.insertSheet(date);
  }
  ss.getSheetByName(date).appendRow(data);
}

Sample Output:

References:

Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)
Map()
appendRow
insertSheet(sheetName)


If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. Feel free to clarify below if this was not the result you want.

Thank you for the response! When I try to create that function and run it I get the following error. Am I not doing something else that's basic that I should know to do?
10:32:38 AM Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
onFormSubmit @ New Tab by Date.gs:3

You don't have to run the code. onFormSubmit(e) will automatically trigger the code if someone submits a form. Try to submit a response and check if it creates a new tab.

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
